# SDL C++ error c3861

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, sdl, game-physics

I have been trying for hours to fix this issue but I can't seem to think what it could be, I'm trying to set up SDL for the first time but I have ran in to so many issues. I'll leave the code and errors below, thanks in advance.

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRendererDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_renderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    return 0;
}
```

the errors that come with this :

> ```
> identifier "SDL_SetRendererDrawColor" is undefined    
> identifier "SDL_renderPresent" is undefined   
> C3861 'SDL_SetRendererDrawColor': identifier not found 
> C3861 'SDL_renderPresent': identifier not found
> ```

after commenting these two out I get this;

> 'My1stSDL.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\My1stSDL\x64\Release\My1stSDL.exe'. Symbols
>   loaded.
>
> 'My1stSDL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'My1stSDL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'My1stSDL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'My1stSDL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> 'My1stSDL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> The thread 0x64f4 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). The
>   thread 0x6634 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). The
>   thread 0x671c has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). The
>   program '[23748] My1stSDL.exe' has exited with code -1073741515
>   (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.

Comment: Please type your errors instead of posting an image. Posting image is a sign of laziness. You have more chance to get help if you show some effort.

Comment: I agree please put your code on SO so we can replicate it on our own computers.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

Two simple typos.

SDL_SetRendererDrawColor -> SDL_SetRenderDrawColor.

SDL_renderPresent -> SDL_RenderPresent.